# Char array to byte array in UTF-8 without using String or Charset

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, utf-8

I have a little question. I have to encode char array with UTF-8 and get the byte array equivalent of it by using Java. Converting the char array to String and than getting the byte array is not an option, String must be avoided, because of security concerns. If I use

```
byte[] encoded = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(CharBuffer.wrap(toBeEncoded)).array();
```

When the length of the input array is more than 9 symbols, the output array has an extra element which is empty. If the length is even longer, there are more empty elements. Then I decode it, I get extra extra more elements. If after encoding I have 1 empty element, after decoding there are two. This is not an option too, because I want to encrypt the encoded value. Thank you.

Comment: _"String must be avoided, because of security concerns."_ can you please elaborate?

Comment: And what do you mean by _"the output array has an extra element which is empty?"_ How is a byte "empty?"

Comment: I mean that that the value of the extra element is 0 and after decoding I get another one. These elements are interpreted as white spaces.

Comment: @MattBall Unfortunately strings in Java are *immutable*. Which means you cannot wipe sensitive information from memory when you're done with it like you can a `Char[]` or `Byte[]` array. (see [heartbleed attack](https://heartbleed.com/))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `Charset.encode()` makes no guarantees about the *capacity* of the buffer it returns.  It very well might allocate extra space at the end, which is what you are seeing.  However, the buffer's *limit* will be set correctly.  In fact, there is no guarantee that the returned buffer will be backed by an array at all (it could be made a direct buffer in future Java versions, who knows?)

To get a properly sized array you'll need to make a properly sized byte array and copy only the data you want from the byte buffer into that array.  Here we use the limit (which is the amount of content actually written into the buffer) to size the new array:

```
ByteBuffer buf = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(toBeEncoded));
byte[] array = new byte[buf.limit()];
buf.get(array);
```

[This article describes the limit, capacity and position of buffers nicely.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/buffers.html#capacity-position-limit)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. I have read about this behavior of Charset.encode(), but I did not know that the buffer's limit is correct. One of my options was to trim the extra elements but in another way, but I wanted another solution like yours. I will read the article for sure. Thank you again. Regards.

Comment: @M.Cherchelanov the documentation for [CharsetEncoder.encode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode-java.nio.CharBuffer-) makes the behaviour more clear: _Returns: A newly-allocated byte buffer containing the result of the encoding operation.  The buffer's position will be zero and its limit will follow the last byte written._